# How to set middle div height 100% depend upon Div A And Div B using css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

- I trying to set 100% height of Div B
- Div-A And Div-B height not Fix
- Div-A always on top
- Div-B always on bottom

Comment: Do you wish to only use HTML and CSS, or are you maybe open to other languages ?

Comment: No, only use HTML And css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flex-direction: column` for this.

**Working Example:**

```js
var header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];
var main = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0];
var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

function changeHeight() {
var newHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;

header.style.flex = '1 0 ' + newHeight + 'px';
footer.style.flex = '1 0 ' + newHeight + 'px';
main.style.height= 'calc(100vh - ' + (newHeight * 2) + 'px)';
}

input.addEventListener('change', changeHeight, false);
```

```css
body {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

header, footer {
flex: 1 0 100px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
}

header h2, footer h2 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

main {
height: calc(100vh - 200px);
overflow: hidden;
}

header, footer, main {
text-align: center;
}

input {
width: 50px;
margin: 24px;
}
```

```html
<header><h2>Header</h2></header>

<main>
<p>You can vertically resize the <strong>Header</strong> and the <strong>Footer</strong>.</p>

<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Resize height of Header and Footer</legend>
<input type="number" value="100" step="10" min="60" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</main>

<footer><h2>Footer</h2></footer>
```

Comment: But only do this using HTML and css

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand. This solution **is** only in HTML and CSS. The javascript widget is there to prove that it works.

Comment: Sorry i didn't check your code, it's working fine thanks and sorry again

Comment: and my header footer height not fix then what can i do ? how to set { .main height: calc(100vh - 200px); } how to minus height into 100vh ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not fix[ed]" and I will try and help you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">

    <title>test</title>
    <style>

.divB{
     height: 100vh;
}
.divA{
     height:64px; 
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;

     background:green;
     width: 100%
}
.divC{
  height:64px;  
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0; 
  background:green;
     width: 100%

 }
 body{
   margin: 0
 }   


     </style>




</head>

<body style="background:red" >


    <div class="divA"></div>
    <div class="divB"></div>
    <div class="divC"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And What About div-c ?

Comment: plz check it again your output

Comment: @dhrupalSuthar now check it out.

Comment: thanks , But some contains  add in Div-B it's start to top of Div-A

Comment: in this code Div-A And Div-C Is behind of Div-B , but i need Div-B is center between Div-A And Div-C not absolute to Div-A And Div-C

Comment: I send you screenshot of this code. use same as its like this. it is working fine on my side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150407/discussion-between-dhrupal-suthar-and-farrukh-hashmi).

Comment: yes it's fine but you can check  Rounin code i need like this

Answer (score 0):

Although you are not using jQuery but if you would like to use jQuery it may be helpful...!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var heightA = $('.a').outerHeight(),
        heightC = $('.c').outerHeight();
    $('.b').css({
        'padding-top': heightA,
        'padding-bottom': heightC
    });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0px; box-sizing: border-box;}
.a, .c {height: auto; background: blue; position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px;}
.a {top: 0px;} .c {bottom: 0px;}
.b {height: 100vh; position: relative; background: #ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">
 <div class="a">
  Div A <br /><br />
 </div>
  Div B
 <div class="c">
  Div C <br /><br />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only Using HTML And css

Comment: i m working on ReactJs and only using HTML,CSS And React js